# add-adgroupmember are NUL values possible?

Tags: powershell

I run the below PS command against a csv file that has a list of AD groups followed by ADUsers.

The script runs fine so long as all the fields are populated, Is there a command / switch that would ignore a non value as such ?

```
import-csv c:\admin\powershell\ADGroupMembers.csv | foreach {add-adgroupmember -Identity $_.ADGroup $_.member1,$_.member2,$_.member3,$_.member4,$_.member5}
```

CSV File Contents

```
ADGroup,Member1,Member2,Member3,Member4,Member5
AD-Test1,Minnie,Mickey,Donald,Daisy,Goofy
AD-Test2,Minnie,Mickey,Donald,,
AD-Test3,Minnie,Mickey,Donald,Pete,Spike
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if one of the member* properties has no value:

```
Import-Csv c:\admin\powershell\ADGroupMembers.csv | Foreach-Object {

    $values = $_.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Name -clike "Member*" -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Value) }

    if($values)
    {
       Write-Warning 'missing values'
    }
    else
    {
       Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.ADGroup $_.member1,$_.member2,$_.member3,$_.member4,$_.member5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you also want to add members of lines containing missing values (e.g. that you want to add Minnie,Mickey and Donald to AD-Test2). In that case I would sculpt our csv file into a collection of objects with two properties: ADGroup (string) and Members (string[]). Then I would feed this collection to add-groupmember.

The collection would look something like this:

```
<#
ADGroup          Members        
-------          -------        
AD-Test1         {Minnie, Mickey, Donald, Daisy...}
AD-Test2         {Minnie, Mickey, Donald}
AD-Test3         {Minnie, Mickey, Donald, Pete...}
#>
```

How to create this collection:

```
# collection creation
$groupmembers = `
import-csv .\ADGroupMembers.csv | 
select AdGroup, @{
  Name = "Members"
  Expression = { 
    $members = @() 
    $_.psobject.properties |  
    Where-Object {$_.Name -clike "Member*" -and (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Value))} | 
    Foreach-Object {$members += $_.value}
    $members 
  }
}
```

Feeding the collection to add-adgroupmember:

```
$groupmembers | %{Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.AdGroup -Members $_.members}
```